# Use conditional operator in Prometheus alert rules to set severity

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-alertmanager

I would like to use the conditional operator into the Prometheus alert.rules definition to set a specific severity.
For instance, if the environment is production, I want to set the severity to critical else another value.

Something like:

```yaml
- alert: CPU load
  expr: expression_used_to_check_load
  for: 15m
  labels:
     severity: if $labels.env == prd -> severity = critical else something else
  annotations:
     summary: Just a summary
     description: "Just a description"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the rule in two:

```yaml
- alert: CPU load
  expr: expression_used_to_check_load and {env=="prd"}
  for: 15m
  labels:
    severity: critical
  annotations:
    summary: Just a summary
    description: "Just a description"
- alert: CPU load
  expr: expression_used_to_check_load and {env!="prd"}
  for: 15m
  labels:
    severity: warning
  annotations:
    summary: Just a summary
    description: "Just a description"
```

Comment: Is duplicating that much information really the only way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than configuring this in the severity itself, you can configure the receiver of your pages differently based on environment.

```yaml
- match: {owner: 'MYTEAM'}
    receiver: 'blackhole'
    routes:
    - match: {severity: 'critical', env: 'staging'}
      receiver: 'myteam-warn'
    - match: {severity: 'critical', env: 'prd'}}
      receiver: 'myteam-page'
```

The different receivers can be configured differently.  `myteam-warn` might just send you an email whereas `myteam-page` might trigger a page.

Comment: I didn't understand, he wants to set "severity = warning" if "env != prd", how your solution does that?

Comment: The severity usually means the different paging rules are used. Rather than changing the severity you can configure different paging rules for the same severity based on staging versus production.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the severity this way.

```
- alert: KubernetesStatefulsetReplicasMismatch
    expr: 'kube_statefulset_status_replicas_ready != kube_statefulset_status_replicas'
    for: 3s
    labels:
      severity: "{{ if eq .Labels.cluster \"prod\" }}critical{{ else if eq .Labels.cluster \"dev\" }}warning{{ end }}"
    annotations:
      summary: Kubernetes StatefulSet replicas mismatch (cluster {{ $labels.cluster }})
      description: "A StatefulSet does not match the expected number of replicas.\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"
```